# How to set {index} of my object array into this.setState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Now I would like to do that when someone push "onPress", a state is changed.
But, in my code I need to {index} or something to identify each state.

So, how to do that?

Could you teach me, please.

```
const Lists =[
  { name: aaa, note: AAA},
  { name: bbb, note: BBB},
  { name: ccc, note: CCC}, 
 ]

state = {
  isVisible0: false,
  isVisible1: false,
  isVisible2: false,
}

///

renderList(){
  return Lists.map((value,index) => {
   return 
   ////
   //
   /
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>  {this.setState({ isVisible{index}:    
 true })}}>

</TouchableOpacity>
})
}
```

Comment: I got a error when use this.setState({isVisble{index} : true})

Answer (score 0):

Try using template literal

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ [`isVisible${index}`]: 
true })}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
renderList(){
return Lists.map((value,index) => {
   return 
   ////
   //
   /
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>  {this.setState({ isVisible{index}:    
 true })}}>

</TouchableOpacity>
})
}
```

To

```
  renderList(){
return Lists.map((value,index) => {
   return 
   ////
   //
   /
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>  {this.setState({ ["isVisible" + index]:    
 true })}}>

</TouchableOpacity>
})
}
```

Comment: @ryonz I have updated my answer please give a try now

Answer (score 0):

Please see the sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wr6nk0w6l

```
const Lists = [
  { name: "aaa", note: "AAA" },
  { name: "bbb", note: "BBB" },
  { name: "ccc", note: "CCC" }
];

class List extends Component {
  state = {
    isVisible0: false,
    isVisible1: false,
    isVisible2: false
  };

  render() {
    return Lists.map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <div onClick={() => this.setState({ [`isVisible${index}`]: true })}>
          Toggle {index} - status:{" "}
          {this.state[`isVisible${index}`] ? "true" : "false"}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}
```